# Как вывести в консоль строчки начинающиеся только с 111?

Tags: c++

Есть файл test.txt. В нем находится

```
"1234567890"
"1112345678"
"1234567890"
"1234567890"
"1118765432"
"ABCABCABCA"
"AAAABCABCA"
"AAADAADBCA"
```

Как вывести только те строчки в консоль где в начале есть 111XXXXXXX? В нашем случае вывести должно вывести

1112345678
1118765432

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема? Сравнивайте три первые символа...

Comment: Проблема вся в том, что нет понятия как сделать это, от слова совсем.

Comment: А ты пытался сам решить. Если да, то напиши тот код, который у тебя получился и скажи что не получается в нем.

Comment: @John ну тогда почитай за открытие потока чтения файлов С++.  https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/8.3.php

Comment: Если С++, то см. [`starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with). Если С-строки, то [`strncmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncmp).

Comment: @Harry starts_with появилось в C++ 20 (вроде) Не все используют этот вариант компилятора

Comment: @John Помечайте ответ как принятый и жмите стрелку вверх :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты для

строки С:

```
const char * s = "1112352327";
if (strncmp(s,"111",3) == 0) // Строка начинается с 111
```

строки C++

```
string s = "11152345646";

if (s.starts_with("111"))    // Строка начинается с 111

if (s.substr(0,3) == "111")  // Строка начинается с 111 

if (s.find("111") == 0)       // Строка начинается с 111
```

Comment: Вы не указали особенности использования например starts_with - начиная с C++20, не все используют новые версии компиляторов

Comment: @Виктор Тогда надо и С++11 упоминать - не все его используют ведь, правда? А некоторые вообще используют С++, в котором и `string` нет... По-моему, в 2022 году стандарт с++20 давно не новинка.

Answer (score -1):

Просто делаем так:

```
std::string str;

// Тут загружаем строку из файла

if (3+7 == str.length() && str.rfind("111",0) == 0 ) {
    // выводим строку
}
```

Разумеется, меняем 3+7 в зависимости от маски. Формируем в общем...

Итоговый код для изучения:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    string line;
    cout << "Found: ";
    int count = 0;
    string mask_str = "111";
    int mask_total_chars = 3 + 7;

    ifstream infile("data.txt"); // Открываем файл

    while (getline(infile, line)) // читаем строку, пока не конец файла
    {
        // Длина строки и начало совпадает с маской?
        if (mask_total_chars == line.length() && line.rfind(mask_str,0) == 0 ) {
            cout << line << " ";  // Да, вывели на экран
            count++; // Количество найденых элементов
        }
    }
    cout << "[" << count << " items]" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Данные в файле data.txt

Вывод:
Found: 1112345678 1118765432 [2 items]

Ответ для @Mikhailo "как насчет строки 1112211133?":

```
  string str ("1112211133");
  string key ("111");
  if (0==str.rfind(key,0))
    cout << str << '\n';
  else
    cout << 'Not Found' << '\n';
```

Вывод: 1112211133

Comment: А как насчет строки `111222111333`? Ее ваш метод отбросит, в то время как она правильная.

Comment: Метод учитывает размер требуемой строки " в начале есть 111XXXXXXX" - 10, а в Вашей строке - 12 символов

Comment: Хорошо, пусть 10 (хотя в условии о 10 символах ни слова) — как насчет строки `1112211133`?

Comment: @Mikhailo смотрите в ответе

Comment: @Mikhailo  "хотя в условии о 10 символах ни слова" - где в начале есть 111XXXXXXX - явно задан размер "XXXXXXX" + "111"